# How to add a delay activity in Microsoft Copilot Studio

Tags: microsoft-copilot

I cannot find a way to add a delay in this topic. The documentation is not useful at all.

I tried using [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/authoring-send-event-activities#sending-other-activity-types) and searched many other options, but I'm missing something. It s literally the same as their docs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO34M.png)